# How is the producer notified when the consumer is down or consumer's connection is lost in rabbitmq .net implementation?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++, rabbitmq, connection

I came across Rabbitmq event exchange plugin which when enabled displays the internal events associated with rabbitmq connections and channels.The problem is that it does not tell which connection is closed or opened. If anyone could suggest some better way so that the producer will get notified when the connection from consumer is lost or whenever the consumer is shut?
Thanks in advance!